# No dropdown menu appears from Dropbox indicator on Cinnamon

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon, dropbox

In Cinnamon, the Dropbox indicator does not have a dropdown menu like in Unity. If possible, how can one be made to display?

Comment: For some reason I don't think the Cinnamon version of Dropbox had the dropdown menu. Can anyone clarify that?